# How to remove silicone from a porous wall?

Tags: walls, removal, silicone

I recently removed a door bell and I got a sillicone stain in the wall. 
The wall is basically red brick.

The brick individually are kind of irregular and present some superficial porosity.

This means that the remaining sillicone is hard to remove.

What can I do to clean it? is there any way to dissolve it?

Are there any home made solutions?

Answer (score 1):

this works fine

http://www.rona.ca/en/paint---silicone-remover

you may have to find a supplier of it or something like it near you.  it takes a lot of time and patience on brick, and you will have to reapply it many times to get it all off, but if you are patient, it removes all traces of silicones.